# Can not resolve com.android.camera.action.CROP in android 11 for first time app is installed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, crop, android-implicit-intent

I am starting implicit intent for crop with string "com.android.camera.action.CROP" on android 11.
when application is first installed can not resolve its activity by this code.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");


    intent.setType("image/*");

    //to check whether there is an cropping app present or not
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

it is not resolving for the first time and runs for second time it gets the activities that can handle the intent.

Answer (score 6):

This code is a code that captures or imports an image from the camera app or gallery app and proceeds with cropping.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final String APP_TAG = "crop";

    public String intermediateName = "1.jpg";
    public String resultName = "2.jpg";

    Uri intermediateProvider;
    Uri resultProvider;

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraActivityResultLauncher;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> galleryActivityResultLauncher;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cropActivityResultLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonCamera = findViewById(R.id.buttonCamera);
        buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onLaunchCamera();
            }
        });

        Button buttonGallery = findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);
        buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPickPhoto();
            }
        });

        cameraActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Bitmap takenImage = loadFromUri(intermediateProvider);
                        ImageView ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.originView);
                        ivPreview.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(takenImage, 400));
                        onCropImage();
                    }
                });

        galleryActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
                        saveBitmapFileToIntermediate(result.getData().getData());
                        Bitmap selectedImage = loadFromUri(intermediateProvider);
                        ImageView ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.originView);
                        ivPreview.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 400));
                        onCropImage();
                    }
                });

        cropActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Bitmap cropImage = loadFromUri(resultProvider);
                        ImageView ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.resultView);
                        ivPreview.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(cropImage, 400));
                    }
                });

    }

    public void onLaunchCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(intermediateName);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            intermediateProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.photostream.crop.fileprovider", photoFile);
        else
            intermediateProvider = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, intermediateProvider);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            cameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    }

    // Trigger gallery selection for a photo
    public void onPickPhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    }

    private void onCropImage() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            grantUriPermission("com.android.camera", intermediateProvider, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            intent.setDataAndType(intermediateProvider, "image/*");

            List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            int size = 0;

            if(list != null) {
                grantUriPermission(list.get(0).activityInfo.packageName, intermediateProvider, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                size = list.size();
            }

            if (size == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error, wasn't taken image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");

                intent.putExtra("scale", true);

                File photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(resultName);
                // wrap File object into a content provider
                // required for API >= 24
                // See https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-files-with-api-24-or-higher
                resultProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.photostream.crop.fileprovider", photoFile);

                intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, resultProvider);
                intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

                Intent cropIntent = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
                cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                grantUriPermission(res.activityInfo.packageName, resultProvider, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                cropIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                cropActivityResultLauncher.launch(cropIntent);
            }
        } else {
            File photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(resultName);
            resultProvider = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

            Intent intentCrop = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            intentCrop.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intentCrop.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intentCrop.setDataAndType(intermediateProvider, "image/*");
            intentCrop.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intentCrop.putExtra("scale", true);
            intentCrop.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            intentCrop.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
            intentCrop.putExtra("return-data", false);
            intentCrop.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, resultProvider);
            cropActivityResultLauncher.launch(intentCrop);
        }
    }

    // Returns the File for a photo stored on disk given the fileName
    public File getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(""), APP_TAG);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
        }
        File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);
        return file;
    }

    public Bitmap loadFromUri(Uri photoUri) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1){
                // on newer versions of Android, use the new decodeBitmap method
                ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                image = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
            } else {
                // support older versions of Android by using getBitmap
                image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    private void saveBitmapFileToIntermediate(Uri sourceUri) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap =  loadFromUri(sourceUri);

            File imageFile = getPhotoFileUri(intermediateName);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                intermediateProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.photostream.crop.fileprovider", imageFile);
            else
                intermediateProvider = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.photostream.crop">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.photostream.crop.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It's working well on Android 11.
You can also refer follow project on Github.
https://github.com/bigant02/image-crop

Answer (score 3):

I assume you target Android 11 (API 30), which requires you to specify all intents to external apps in a `queries` node inside your AndroidManifest.xml like follows:

```
<queries>
    ...
    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP" />
    </intent>
    ...
</queries>
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility). Also there's a medium post on the matter [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9).

**NOTE**:
The intent `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is based on the camera app from AOSP which might be missing on some devices, please refer to Commonsware's old blogpost about it: https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: That's indeed weird. Could you confirm you have these entries in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 30

Comment: inserted above given lines but the problem persists.

Comment: there is a change of behavior that now cropping activity will not be resolved until application opens google photos to view gallery.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm using the following `<queries>` config in AndroidManifest.xml and it works.

```
<manifest>
  // ...
  <queries>
      <intent>
          <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP" />
          <data android:scheme="content"
            android:mimeType="image/*"/>
      </intent>
  </queries>
</manifest>
```

And the **resolveActivity**:

```
    val intent = Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP").apply {
        type = "image/*"
        data = photoUri
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
        // grant uri permission here
    }
```

After some test, I found the key is that the **android:mimeType** in `queries` must align with the `type` which is set in the Intent.

Comment: combine with grantUriPermission() it works.

Comment: is it necessary to set scheme="content"  ?  What is the meaning of that? Because in this case: action crop, don't need that.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. To set scheme = content is correct in this case. Without it, the content: and file: schemes are assumed