# gallery pick then crop the photo gives my blank image

Tags: java, android, image, crop, pickup

I'm trying to follow the example of @bigant02 on [Can not resolve com.android.camera.action.CROP in android 11 for first time app is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571762/can-not-resolve-com-android-camera-action-crop-in-android-11-for-first-time-app) (not enough reputation to post there) but, if I can pick my photo and show it if needed, if I send this Uri to a cropImage(), I get empty image to crop
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYsPN.jpg)
I don't understand if it is a problem with my code or a permission problem

**my code :**

```
    public static void cropUri(ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher, final Uri selectedUri, int width, int height) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // this will open all images in the Galery
        intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "image/*");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra("crop", true);
        // this defines the aspect ration
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", width);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", height);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedUri);
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
```

Tried too with :

```
private void cropImage(ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher, final Uri selectedUri, int width, int height) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        grantUriPermission("com.android.camera", selectedUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        int size = 0;
        if(list != null) {
            grantUriPermission(list.get(0).activityInfo.packageName, selectedUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            size = list.size();
        }
        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error, wasn't taken image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", width);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", height);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedUri);
            intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            grantUriPermission(res.activityInfo.packageName, selectedUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            cropIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            activityResultLauncher.launch(cropIntent);
        }
    } else {
        Intent intentCrop = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intentCrop.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intentCrop.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intentCrop.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "image/*");
        intentCrop.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intentCrop.putExtra("scale", true);
        intentCrop.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        intentCrop.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
        intentCrop.putExtra("return-data", false);
        intentCrop.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedUri);
        cropResultLauncher.launch(intentCrop);
    }
}
```

not better.

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- permission required to automatically restart a repeating alarm if the user reboots the device -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP" />
        <data
            android:scheme="content"
            android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan">
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <activity
        android:name=".ConnectActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrefsActivity"
        android:label="@string/prefsTitle" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RangtActivity"
        android:label="@string/rangtTitle"
        android:parentActivityName=".ConnectActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ConnectActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StockActivity"
        android:label="@string/stockTitle"
        android:parentActivityName=".RangtActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".RangtActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProductActivity"
        android:label="@string/productTitle"
        android:parentActivityName=".StockActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".StockActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".barcode.BarcodeCaptureActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".NotificationActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There is no `CROP` `Intent` in Android. There are [several dozen image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created), though -- find one that you like and use it!

Comment: Ah... ok, so what is com.android.camera.action.CROP ?

In fact, I need the user is able to crop an image from gallery and/or camera (I want to be able to fix rate width/height for him), not saving the result to external storage, just returning a bitmap that I'll modify and save myself to internal app storage.
Can you suggest me one of them to do that only please ?

Comment: "so what is com.android.camera.action.CROP" -- it is an undocumented, unsupported `Intent` action from an app that not everybody has (if that app even still supports that action).